# Errors in a testing android project

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I'm trying to run this code (android app):

manifest file:

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testamish"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Results"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_results" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SpinnerDemo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spinner_demo" >
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.example.testamish.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

However, when trying to launch this on a virtual device, I get those errors and I don't get why (code has no errors/warnings):

```
10-17 17:07:22.685: E/Trace(819): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 17:07:23.430: D/AndroidRuntime(819): Shutting down VM
10-17 17:07:23.430: W/dalvikvm(819): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x40a13300)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testamish/com.example.testamish.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testamish.MainActivity
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testamish.MainActivity
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-17 17:07:23.445: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post the code to `com.example.testamish.MainActivity` and show its entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: I dont have mainactivity file, my 2 java files are named Results.java and SpinnerDemo.java

Comment: @Ravind Maurya I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Remove this from you Manifest (from the original one!):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And add this four line to the Activity, you want to start on launch:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

## Details

In Android, the data&actions between activities is driven by `Intent`s. When you want to launch an app, it's kind an action between the Launcher app, and your app. It's also an Intent, when you start the Gallery, to choose an image for Facebook, or to start the Twitter app, to share something.

You can define in the `Manifest.xml`, for each `Activity` of your app, to which Intents to catch. You defined a `MainActivity` in your Manifest, and set to catch the `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` intents. These two Intents responds, to start the app from the Launcher.

So the emulator was finding for your MainActivity, 'cause it read from you Manifest, to start that. But cannot found it, so throw an exception.

Comment: I want spinnerdemo to launch first, I added the 4 lines in manifest file under         <activity
            android:name=".SpinnerDemo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spinner_demo" >but I get an error in manifest file it says parser exception The markup of the document root of Prev The Element mite Have not correct format.

Comment: @Johnny_b: and, is that running? If not, please post your _ORIGINAL_ manifest, and that only. Not with this weird markup, with the edits... (You should have asked about the parsing error... How did you found, to include that element about the `MainActivity`?)

Comment: its not since theres the error I said in the manifest file. I never touched the original manifest file so I dont know what to do im really new(beginner) to android programming...

Comment: @Johnny_b paste here (at the end of your original post!) your Manifest, which says parsing error! That's only!

Comment: I edited the manifest file in my post,see actual manifest file that has the error in it

Comment: @Johnny_b, please post it again, I think our edits has conflicted. Sorry!

Comment: I said __ORIGINAL__!!! Do you have these in your Manifest!? `<<<<<<< Original` or `=======` or maybe `>>>>>>> Added`? If yep, delete _EVERYTHING_ before `<?xml` and after `</manifest>` (the first one)

Comment: I finally managed to make it works,your first solution was correct,I dont know why it wasnt working at first.sorry about that and thanks a lot!